# Google plus token and gcm registration token

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-plus, google-signin

For my application, I need token for logging in with google plus. Now, I dont know where to get the token. Is google plus token the same as gcm token?

Comment: no they are different

Comment: @tyczj ok, how to obtain it from fragment?

Comment: wait what token are you talking about

Comment: Google sign in token

Comment: @tyczj  
Google sign in token

Comment: there is no google sign in token, please be more specific

Comment: @tyczj what do I get then when logging in with google plus?

Comment: Nothing, on connected gets called. Have you read any of the documentation

Comment: @tyczj I have read and im getting user information, name, email, picture, id, etc... But, I need access token, just like when you login on facebook, you get access token. How do I obtain it?

Comment: what do you need an access token for, you need to give more details on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @tyczj I need auth token to send to my server so user can register to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to read this section of the docs about how to get an auth key to send to your server

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

```
private class GetIdTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
        Account account = new Account(accountName, GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        String scopes = "audience:server:client_id:" + SERVER_CLIENT_ID; // Not the app's client ID.
        try {
            return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), account, scopes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving ID token.", e);
            return null;
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving ID token.", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ID token: " + result);
        if (result != null) {
          // Successfully retrieved ID Token
          // ...
        } else {
          // There was some error getting the ID Token
          // ...
        }
    }

}
```